# Can I include the schematic and layout I designed on Altium CircuitMaker in my thesis?

Tags: thesis, electrical-engineering

I’m currently seeking my masters degree. Part of what I do is testing the design on a PCB. My institute doesn’t have OrCad or Altium Designer licenses, so I opted for the free Altium CircuitMaker. However, one of my colleagues has pointed out that its results can’t be accepted in an official thesis. So I want to make sure, is he right? Should I halt it and start looking for a way to get a fund for one of the commercial programs?

Comment: What does your supervisor say?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “can’t be accepted in an official thesis”? Is this a legal/licensing restriction of the free software, or are products created using this software considered of too inferior a quality, or is it some other issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague is plainly wrong: You put on your thesis the outcome of your work with the tools you have used, regardless of whether they are applications worth thousands of euros or free ones (that are worth thousands of euros anyway).

Comment: That’s what I was thinking too. Thanks a lot!